# Wordpress category with 404 error

Tags: htaccess, 404-error

Okay, so I'm facing a weird problem as I'm receiving 404 errors on blog category pages and I already did the most popular tricks to solve it, such as:

- re-install Wordpress
- update permalinks
- update .htaccess file
- delete the .htaccess file so WordPress could create a new one automatically
- disable all plugins
- change theme

Nothing seems to work. One day was working fine and the next day not.

I have the same theme and most of the plugins installed in another website of mine and is running without any problem.

Any idea of what could be? 
I'm trying to solve this for several days now without any success.

Thank you in advance.